# Open HTML files in Microsoft WORD without internet connection, How to exclude popup alerts?

Tags: vb.net, vba, vb6, ms-word

I've write an automated application in VB6 (and also in VB.NET) that opens an HTML documents for printing.
My function works fine, without human interaction.

Now we have put application machine off-line.

When you open an HTML with Ms Word (all versions), it try to download all html internet reference (images, css), but it fails and show me a popup that alert me failed to download CSS and Images.

I've not found an advanced option that deny files download from internet, in Word application and in Ole Word Object. 
The problem is that the following code is blocked at third line because wait human interaction clicking on "OK" in popup.

```
ObjectName = "Word.Application"
Set OleObj = CreateObject(ObjectName)
Set OleDoc = OleObj.Documents.Open(FileIn, False, True ,False, "password") 'Block here
OleDoc.PrintOut PrintToFile:=False, Background:=False
```

Do you know Word Option, registry option or custom VB or .NET code that exlude popup or deny download associated css or image files from internet?
Help me,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered using a browser (i.e. Internet Explorer) rather than a Word processor to render your pages for printing? You can host IE in .net apps pretty easily and tell it to print. I haven't tried, but I imagine you'd just get a timeout (i.e. a wait) rather than a popup in your situation.

Comment: @Bob Sammers I think that this is best solution now, but there are a lot of operation that my function do before print document (substitute word, adjust font etc).

Comment: That sounds messy. You might be better extracting the text from your HTML document, substituting words and sending it directly to the printer using whatever formatting you need (i.e. fonts, sizes) etc. How feasible this is depends largely on how simple and / or predictable your input documents will be. The HTML Agility Pack may help, but I haven't used it myself (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried...

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
```

...before trying to open your document?

I don't know if it will take care of this specific error message popup since Word does have a few anti-virus protection popups that can't be turned off. That's one reason why it's less than ideal for a production unattended processing application. I'd strongly recommend looking at some other tools to achieve your project goal.

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts` doesn't accept a `Boolean` input for Word.  There's three constants used instead: `wdAlertsAll`, `wdAlertsMessageBox` and `wdAlertsNone`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Adrian I've been working with automating Excel recently and I only recalled the Boolean. As I stated, I avoid automating Word as much as possible, too many headaches. I'll edit my original.

Comment: Thanks @jfrankcarr you're the best!! this is solution for my code: `OleObj.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone` before open my document! Great